# Foreign key constraint : alternative for one to one relation with split tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

For tables like this:

Book

```
| id | type
+----+--------
| 1  | audio
| 2  | paper

PK id SEQUENCE
```

AudioBook

```
| book_id | type
+---------+-----------
| 1       | audio

FK book_id references Book
FK constraint book_id + type references Book
```

PaperBook

```
| book_id | type
+---------+--------
| 2       | paper

FK book_id references Book
FK constraint book_id + type references Book
```

Is there other way to ensure that `PaperBook` and `AudioBook` will not have same `book_id` without `type` column on them (remove `FK constraint book_id + type references Book` and type on childs?

---

Example without fk constraint where AudioBook and PaperBook can have `book_id=1` at the same time:

Book

```
| id | type
+----+--------
| 1  | audio
| 2  | paper

PK id SEQUENCE
```

AudioBook

```
| book_id 
+---------
| 1       

FK book_id references Book
```

PaperBook

```
| book_id 
+---------
| 2       

FK book_id references Book
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

approach one: foreign key constraints ensure data integrity between the parent table and children tables.  a foreign key constraint prevents the child table from inputting a value for a key not found in the parent table.

without type, you will want to use a guid to keep the key unique on the foreign constraint.   I don't like guids because you lose readibility.

approach two:  in general a foreign key id is a unique number referenced in the parent table.  if you are sharing between multiple tables and a single parent id than consider creating a many to many table to join the tables using key id and type, a cross reference table for lookup.

you can populate and remove items from the cross reference table using a trigger